# REPL - Figwheel won't connect to re-natal app

Tags: react-native, adb, clojurescript, figwheel, re-natal

I'm starting an app from Re-Natal template (didn't change it; `project.clj` from https://github.com/drapanjanas/re-natal/blob/master/resources/project.clj).

Then I ran

```
react-native start
re-natal use-android-device avd
re-natal use-figwheel
lein figwheel android
react-native run-android
```

The app runs ok on the device, but the repl stays at `Prompt will show when Figwheel connects to your application`, and the code won't reload.
The same happens on a `real` android device.

I'm also reloading the app after it starts.

Am I missing something?

---

#### Update: output from `react-native run-android`

```
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 36.329 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Running /home/ale/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (/home/ale/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.renatal/com.renatal.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.renatal/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: I used the steps as you listed (other than `re-natal init FutureApp` to instantiate a new project), and Figwheel did indeed connect. Is there logging output that you could add from `react-native run-android`? I'm thinking specifically after `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Comment: @nrako see updated post for the output

Comment: Hmm... that looks okay. I am not sure. Ran across this comment one of the issues, perhaps there's a versioning issue? `For react native 0.49+ you have to use re-natal 0.8+` [link](https://github.com/drapanjanas/re-natal/issues/170#issuecomment-370552264)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this in other cases as well but one case in which this will happen is when you have done a production build with Leiningen and not subsequently re-run `re-natal use-figwheel`. To solve this you would have to

1. Run `re-natal use-figwheel`
2. Relaunch `react-native start` / `npm run start`
3. Reload the Android app.